# Questions about ANOVA analysis in R of groups

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis, anova

I'm doing ANOVA analysis on a dataset that looks like:

| ID | cluster | gender | description | country | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 124 | 1 | F | SMALL | US | 32 |
| 324 | 1 | M | MEDIUM | CA | 12 |
| 82 | 5 | F | SMALL | US | 45 |
| 453 | 2 | F | LARGE | AU | 34 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 473 | 3 | M | SMALL | DK | 32 |
| 172 | 4 | M | LARGE | US | 62 |
| 23 | 4 | F | LARGE | US | 23 |

This dataset is a summary of the data. My data is divided into 5 clusters, and I would like to see how all the other variables, except ID, are unique to each cluster. I was recommended to use an ANOVA analysis for this. I got some results, but they didn't quite line up with what I saw graphically. For example, I thought gender would be statistically significant given my bar graph visualization, but it's not. This is okay if true (obviously there is nothing I can do about it), but I wanted to check to be sure I was doing this correctly and to see if there is a different way to do this other than ANOVA.

here is what I have been doing:

```
one.way.gender <- aov(cluster ~ gender, data = data1)
summary(one.way.gender)

one.way.description <- aov(cluster ~ description, data = data1)
summary(one.way.description)

one.way.country <- aov(cluster ~ country, data = data1)
summary(one.way.country)

one.way.age <- aov(cluster ~ age, data = data1)
summary(one.way.age)
```

I know this is a very simple way of doing this, and I'm worried I'm missing something. I've went through a few tutorials with more lengthy code to the analysis, but they yield the same results as the simple code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### for categorical data use chi-square test:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# Categorical variables
variables <- c("gender", "description", "country")

# chi-square test 
result <- variables %>% 
  map(~chisq.test(df$cluster, df[[.]]))

result

# output: 

[[1]]

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  df$cluster and df[[.]]
X-squared = 2.9167, df = 4, p-value = 0.5719


[[2]]

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  df$cluster and df[[.]]
X-squared = 9.3333, df = 8, p-value = 0.315


[[3]]

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  df$cluster and df[[.]]
X-squared = 16.625, df = 12, p-value = 0.1643
```

#### for numeric data use Kruskal Wallis test:

```
# numeric variables
kruskal_age <- kruskal.test(age ~ cluster, data = df)
print(kruskal_age)

# output
    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  age by cluster
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 2.5909, df = 4, p-value = 0.6284
```